# My variables will not take any value

Tags: c++, arrays, function, variables, for-loop

Hello I am having trouble with this variable `Total_vot` I do not know why but the value that i want the total votes from vote[i] to add up and that value will become Total_vot. But it it says that the variable is uninitialized which means that i didn't put a zero at the time i created the variable. I want the value to be all the added up votes. but it doesn't work why?

I'm a slight beginner so please be kind :)

```
int Total_vot;

    double *POV = new double[ppl];  
    cout << "this is the percentage of votes each candidate got!" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++)
    { 
        Total_vot  += vote[i];
    } 
    cout << Total_vot << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++)
    {
        POV[i] = vote[i] / Total_vot * 100;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++)
    {

        cout << cans[i]; cout << "     " << vote[i]; cout << "     " << POV[i]; cout<<"%" << endl << endl;
```

Comment: You want `int Total_vot = 0;`

Comment: yes but when i do that the total is always 0 then the program divides 0 by 100 breaking my program. the for loop with the += should add the total vot to around 3000 then give me a percent but it doesn't

Comment: @Darkaura You really do need `int Total_vot = 0;` . There are other problems as well. The loop doesn't add the votes anyway, you are just seeing garbage results when you do not have this line.

Comment: Please use `std::vector<double>` rather than creating an array of doubles.

Comment: What you describe depends entirely on the values in `ppl` and `vote`, which you are not showing us.

Comment: change `POV[i] = vote[i] / Total_vot * 100;` to `POV[i] = 1.0 * vote[i] / Total_vot * 100;`

Comment: You may want to multipy by 100 before dividing.  And that should be 100.0 (with decimal point), to indicate the number is double precision instead of integer.

Comment: Or to stick with integer math, `POV[i] = vote[i] * 100 / Total_vot;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb hey that was the answer thanks i'm surprised that worked my program works beautifully.

Comment: @Darkaura Cool. Barmar's answer says much the same thing so you can accept that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to initialize `Total_vot`:

```
int Total_vot = 0;
```

That will get rid of the warning about the uninitialized variable, and the total will be correct.

Second, the assignment

```
POV[i] = vote[i] / Total_vot * 100;
```

is performing integer arithmetic because all the operands are integers. When it divides `vote[i]` by `Total_vot` this will be a fraction, and will be rounded down to `0`. It doesn't matter that you're assigning to a `double`; first it calculates the result of the expression, then it converts that result to `double` for the assignment.

You need to cast at least one of the operands to `double` before doing the division:

```
POV[i] = vote[i] / (double) Total_vot * 100;
```